# Different format Date objects don't equal

Tags: java, date, java-7

I have this code that compares two Date objects. They store dates in different format but they have the same day in meaning.

```
public class DateTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        compareDate();
    }

    public static void compareDate() {
        try {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'ICT' yyyy");
            Date date = df.parse("Thu Jan 22 03:16:26 ICT 2015");
            System.out.println(date.toString());

            DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
            Date date2 = df2.parse("2015-01-22 03:16:26.723");
            System.out.println(date2.toString());

            System.out.println(date.after(date2));
            System.out.println(date2.after(date));
            System.out.println(date2.equals(date));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output in my machine gives:

```
Thu Jan 22 03:16:26 ICT 2015
Thu Jan 22 03:16:26 ICT 2015
false
true
false
```

It apparently shows that two Date are equals but why date2.after(date) returns true?

Excuse me if this is a basic problem.

Comment: Millisecond percision

Comment: If you take a look at the number of milliseconds each date equates to `date` = `1421856986000` and `date2` = `1421856986723` there is a difference of milliseconds

Comment: Why did you expect `03:16:26.723` NOT to be later than `03:16:26`?

Answer (score 4):

The `Date` class is maybe a bit confusingly named, because it does not represent a "date" (a day), but a precise timestamp.

Your `date2` is later because it includes 723 milliseconds (which the other does not, so they are 000 there).

The format you use to print it just does not show that.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look the the implementation of java.util.Date.after(Date) which compares the millis portion of two dates.

```
/**
     * Tests if this date is after the specified date.
     *
     * @param   when   a date.
     * @return  <code>true</code> if and only if the instant represented 
     *          by this <tt>Date</tt> object is strictly later than the 
     *          instant represented by <tt>when</tt>; 
     *          <code>false</code> otherwise.
     * @exception NullPointerException if <code>when</code> is null.
     */
    public boolean after(Date when) {
        return getMillisOf(this) > getMillisOf(when);
    }
```